# Gif image EXIF tags

Tags: windows, metadata, gif, exif

Is it possible to set a gif image's tags using the Windows properties panel?

It currently seems working on jpeg, but not on gif files.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

GIF files don't support EXIF tags and here's why.

There is a great misconception about JPEG files. Actually, JPEG isn't an image file format - it's a compression algorithm. JPEG specs don't describe how to pack compressed image into file. There are two (mostly compatible) formats for that: the older JFIF and the newer EXIF. Most modern software will also accept mixed formats.

So EXIF isn't a tagging system. Entire JPEG image files are in fact EXIF (or JFIF) files and tagging is one of EXIF's features. GIFs don't use EXIF at all, so you can't put EXIF tags on them.

Comment: learnt something today, +1

Answer (score 14):

GIF files have **Comment** tags that can be updated. While they don't support embedding of [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data, they [*do* support](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/GIF.html) embedding [XMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) metadata/tags.

I always turn to [**ExifTool**](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) for all my tagging needs. The following command will allow you to update the **Comment** tag:

```
exiftool -comment="This is a comment!" Sample.gif
```

You can see a list of all supported XMP tags [here](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/XMP.html), and the XMP EXIF tags supported are listed [here](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/XMP.html#exif).

For example, to specify **FlashMode** (integer) as *Off* you can use (note the **#**):

```
exiftool -FlashMode#=2 Sample.gif
```

To specify **FlashFired** (boolean) as *False*, use:

```
exiftool -FlashFired=false Sample.gif
```

and so on.

**Note:** *-FlashMode* is a shortcut for *-XMP-exif:FlashMode*. See the ExifTool documentation for details. Also, I don't currently know of any way to make Windows aware of these tags though. Maybe there's a shell extension available, will update this answer if I find one.

Answer (score 2):

EXIF is a data collection system used in jpeg files taken on cameras to provide state information (thumbnail, exposure, ISO speed, date, time, location, etc) about when the picture was taken. Since it is native to this type of file, Windows allows manipulation of a subset of the data (similar to MP3 file tags). Other files that can have EXIF information are TIFF and WAV files

GIF is an older format that may have text headers, but the format never was extended to include EXIF information.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, there's no EXIF data for GIFs. However, I did find the below application that will change the creation date of the file and then it will organize in your browser with the other photos with that EXIF date when sorted by creation date!

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html